# When sending ajax POST FormData object key and value are not as set

Tags: javascript, ajax, angular, form-data

I am programatically setting a FormData like so:

```
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('id', '12345678');
```

After which I am sending a POST request with this object. (using angular HttpClient).

I am using Postman to debug the request and see what values were sent by importing the request as cURL and I see that the formData values appear differently.

```
key:------WebKitFormBoundaryI1mdsdmKkradYVMS\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name

value: "id"\r\n\r\n12345678\r\n------WebKitFormBoundaryI1mdsdmKkradYVMS--\r\n
```

What am I doing wrong?

I want to the send the data so that the server will receive an x-form-urlencoded request with the following object:

```
key: id
value: 12345678
```

EDIT: The solution is this:

```
 const body = new URLSearchParams({id: "12345678"});

    const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      })
    };
    return this.http.post(url, body.toString(), httpOptions).pipe(mergeMap( (response:any) => {
      console.log('response ', response);
      return of (response);
    }));
```

Thanks,
Yaron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) objects generate `multipart/form-data`, not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` by default.

They are designed for handling file uploads for which there are no standard encoding method in `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

Use a [URLSearchParams object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams) if you want to generate `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data.

```js
const formData = new FormData();
formData.append('id', '12345678');
const query = new URLSearchParams(formData);
console.log(query.toString());
```

Comment: This still doesn't work. Cannot init URLSearchParams with formData. I am trying to init it instead with {id:'12345678'} which works fine. But when sending the POST request I'm getting an empty Form Data.

Comment: @Yaron — Do you mean that this specific demo not work? That suggests your browser doesn't support the feature. You could use `URLSearchParams` directly and skip `FormData` entirely then. Or perhaps you are trying to upload a file, in which case see the second paragraph of this answer and don't try to use `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` for something it isn't suited for.

Comment: Indeed I skipped the FormData part and set URLSearchParams directly. I'm not uploading a file - just setting some params. Can't get it to work as a x-www-form-urlencoded key-value pairs.

Comment: If you're setting the URLSearchParams directly, and have confirmed the generated data is correct with `console.log`, then the problem must be with how you are putting that in your HTTP request, which isn't in the code you've shared with us.

Comment: I am sending {id:'12345678'} in the body and the request I get is a Form Data object whose key is : {"id": "12345678"} and value is empty. I don't manage to create a key-value pair.

Comment: @Yaron — If you put `{id:'12345678'}` in the body, then I wouldn't expect a FormData object at all. I really don't understand what you are doing. You need to provide a [mcve], not a vague description.

Comment: const httpOptions = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Content-Type':  'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
      })
    };
    return this.http.post(url, {id:'12345678'}, httpOptions).pipe(mergeMap( (response:any) => {
      console.log('response ', response);
      return of (response);
    }));

Comment: @Yaron — Where's `URLSearchParams`? It's no good ignoring my answer and then telling me it doesn't work.

Comment: I did try that as well - I am setting a URLSearchParams object and sending it as the body. That results in an empty {} Form Data object. I can also send it the way Maryannah suggested fits angular and send it as the 3rd parameter - but that didn't work either. I'll update the code in the question.

Comment: @Yaron — *How* are you setting it as the body? Did you convert it to a string as per the demo in the answer? Provide a [mcve].

Comment: That did it.  sending body as a string works ! Thank you. I'll post the working example in my edited question. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 0):

@Quentin's answer is all good, but not that suited to Angular.

Simply pass a second parameter to your GET call :

```
return this.http.get<any>('url', { params: { id: '123456789' }});
```

You don't need to make post requests to add url parameters, and you don't need post requests if you don't provide a body.

Comment: I might be misremembering, but doesn't that make an `application/json` encoded POST request? Not an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` one?

Comment: @Quentin indeed, edited my answer to explain the difference between your answer and mine :)

Comment: You didn't address my comment, and I don't think you understand my answer or the question. The `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` encoding is used for both POST request bodies **and** the query string component of a URL. The question is about using that encoding for a POST request body, and the output of a URLSearchParams object can be used in a POST request body.

Comment: This way the params are passed in the url, but the Form Data object is empty : {}. I need the params to be in the Form Data object, the way I can send them in a Postman POST request of x-www-urlencoded call.

Comment: @Quentin well I said indeed to imply that you were right, it's kind of addressing the comment, isn't it ? But i probably didn't understand the question, you're right. For me, URL params can be added like this, I have almost never used form-urlencoded requests. I thought the OP only wanted to add params to his URL.

Comment: @Yaron, what's your exact purpose ? Could you explain it ? (not in a [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info), rahter the goal you're trying to achieve)

Comment: @Marryannah I'd like to send a POST request to the server in a x-www-urlencoded Form Data key-value pair. (in my case the data is key:id , value:12345678).

Comment: @Yaron yes I know that, but **in order to do what** ?

Comment: @Maryannah To perform something on the server. I know this method of sending request is not ideal (a json raw body would be better) but it's out of my scope - the server needs to get the data that way.